# Internet Explorer 8 - title of the page showing on print

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing

When i print any page from IE8 it also includes page title on top of every page. but chrome does not show up the title.

How do I hide the title on print in IE ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's part of the printer setup settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Print -> Page Setup, you can choose which elements of the page should be printed.

[image: Page Setup]

[image]